# dynamically request an item from db and post it on the page joomla

Tags: php, ajax, post, database-connection, joomla3.0

I'm trying to achieve the following:

1. on page load
2. get the data (article id(s) ) from the local storage
3. make then a db query to retrieve the text of the article with the id
4. display on the same page the text of the article

I have this code

**jQuery code** (is in the index.php file - when user is on the certain page this code is activated)

```
 <script>
 //get the object from local storage and then get the id's of the articles 

 var plantList = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( 'myPlantList' ));

 var articleIds = [];
 for(i=0; i < plantList.length; i++){
 articleIds.push(plantList[i].itemId);
 console.log(articleIds +" array of the items"); //logs fine - this part works
 }

 //send the array of the id's via post

  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'article_list.php',
    data:   {articleIds: articleIds}, 
    success: function(data){
        //jQuery(".art-layout-cell.art-content").append(data);
        console.log(data);//console logs an empty line ????
        console.log('success'); // console logs success
    },
    error: function(){
    console.log("error");
    }

    });

   </script>
```

**article_list.php**

```
  <?php

 defined('_JEXEC') or die;

 JHtml::_('behavior.framework', true);

 if ( isset($_POST["articleIds"]) ) {
 $articleIds = json_decode($_POST["articleIds"]);
 //$articleIds = array(28,30); // I have tried just to set the array, to see what will happen - this didn't work either

 $customArticleList ="<div id='mylist-articles'>";

 foreach($articleIds as $value) {

    $db = JFactory::getDbo();

    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select($db->quoteName('introtext'));
    $query->from($db->quoteName('#__content'));
    $query->where($db->quoteName('id')." = ".$db->quote(intval($value)));

    $db->setQuery($query);

  // Load the results 
  $result = $db->loadResult();

  $customArticleList .= "<div class='list-article'>". $result. '</div>';

}

$customArticleList .= "</div>";

echo $customArticleList;

}else{
echo "nothing received";
}
?>
```

So The request is sent and the data is received back. But why do I get an empty data results????

Call to data base worked fine in index.php (I have just replaced then the $_POST array with the predefined array, like array(1,2) - and the call to database returned me the required articles...)

Anyone please a hint!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Small edit: I have added to the ajax call dataType: "json", now I get the response logged "null" in the console.... Is there a mistake in the php code then? Any help will be highly appreciated....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I want to answer my question myself..

the thirst thing was the javascript: I had to declare the expected type or response, which in my case is html so

```
     dataType: "html",
```

secondly the problem was also with the joomla rules of viewing custom php files
instead of the first 2 lines

```
 defined('_JEXEC') or die;
 JHtml::_('behavior.framework', true);
```

I had to add:

```
 define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
 define('JPATH_BASE', '/../../../../public_html'); //path to the root folder of the joomla instalation
 require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
 require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );
```

I hope that this saves someone's time in the future...

Comment: Thanks! I have found it :-) but nether the less appreciate your comment ;-)